# Object 'xxx' not found while deploying random forest in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry if it has been asked before. I try to deploy my random forest model to shiny app. but when I try, it says "Object'Region' not found.
I'm not sure what is wrong. I also wonder how to make a print of predicted test set in R.
I really highly appreciate any help. Thank you ver much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEMdG.png)
Here's my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(randomForest)
library(DT)

# Read in the RF model
model <- readRDS("ModelRF.rds")

# User interface                   

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  
  # Page header
  headerPanel('Flood Predictor'),
  
  # Input values
  sidebarPanel(
    #HTML("<h3>Input parameters</h3>"),
    tags$label(h3('Input parameters')),
    
    numericInput("RR", 
                 label = "Daily Rainfall", 
                 value = 13),
    numericInput("Forest_Ratio", 
                 label = "Forest Ratio", 
                 value = 0.59),
    numericInput("Streamflow", 
                 label = "Streamflow", 
                 value = 9.97),
    
    
    actionButton("submitbutton", "Submit", 
                 class = "btn btn-primary")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    tags$label(h3('Status/Output')), # Status/Output Text Box
    verbatimTextOutput('contents'),
    tableOutput('tabledata') # Prediction results table
    
  )
)


# Server                           
server<- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Input Data
  datasetInput <- reactive({  
    
    df <- data.frame(
      Name = c(
               "Daily Rainfall",
               "Forest Ratio",
               "Streamflow"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$RR,
                             input$Forest_Ratio,
                             input$Streamflow)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    Flood <- 0
    df <- rbind(df, Flood)
    input <- transpose(df)
    write.table(input,"input.csv", sep=",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    
    test <- read.csv(paste("input", ".csv", sep=""), header = TRUE)
    
    Output <- data.frame(Prediction=predict(model,test), round(predict(model,test,type="prob"), 3))
    print(Output)
    
  })
  
  # Status/Output Text Box
  output$contents <- renderPrint({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate("Calculation complete.") 
    } else {
      return("Server is ready for calculation.")
    }
  })
  
  # Prediction results table
  output$tabledata <- renderTable({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate(datasetInput()) 
    } 
  })
  
}


# Create the shiny app             
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Does your code work without the shiny overhead at all? Your `test` data does not seem to include any region value, which *might* be why your `predict`ion fails (if region is part of the model params).